# Why does Sleep() slow down subsequent code for 40ms?

Tags: c++, windows, performance, sleep

I originally asked about this at coderanch.com, so if you've tried to assist me there, thanks, and don't feel obliged to repeat the effort. coderanch.com is mostly a Java community, though, and this appears (after some research) to really be a Windows question, so my colleagues there and I thought this might be a more appropriate place to look for help.

I have written a short program that either spins on the Windows performance counter until 33ms have passed, or else calls Sleep(33). The former exhibits no unexpected effects, but the latter appears to (inconsistently) slow subsequent processing for about 40ms (either that, or it has some effect on the values returned from the performance counter for that long). After the spin or Sleep(), the program calls a routine, runInPlace(), that spins for 2ms, counting the number of times it queries the performance counter, and returning that number.

When the initial 33ms delay is done by spinning, the number of iterations of runInPlace() tends to be (on my Windows 10, XPS-8700) about 250,000. It varies, probably due to other system overhead, but it varies smoothing around 250,000.

Now, when the initial delay is done by calling Sleep(), something strange happens. A lot of the calls to runInPlace() return a number near 250,000, but quite a few of them return a number near 50,000. Again, the range varies around 50,000, fairly smoothly. But, it is clearly averaging one or the other, with nearly no returns anywhere between 80,000 and 150,000. If I call runInPlace() 100 times after each delay, instead of just once, it never returns a number of iterations in the smaller range after the 20th call. As runInPlace() runs for 2ms, this means the behavior I'm observing disappears after 40ms. If I have runInPlace() run for 4ms instead of 2ms, it never returns a number of iterations in the smaller range after the 10th call, so, again, the behavior disappears after 40ms (likewise if have runInPlace() run for only 1ms; the behavior disappears after the 40th call).

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"

int runInPlace(int msDelay)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t0, t1;
    int n = 0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t0);

    do
    {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
            n++;
    } while (t1.QuadPart - t0.QuadPart < msDelay);

    return n;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t0, t1;
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    int n;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

    int msDelay = 2 * frequency.QuadPart / 1000;

    int spinDelay = 33 * frequency.QuadPart / 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (argc > 1)
            Sleep(33);
        else
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&t0);

            do
            {
                    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
            } while (t1.QuadPart - t0.QuadPart < spinDelay);
        }

        n = runInPlace(msDelay);
        printf("%d \n", n);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's some output typical of what I get when using Sleep() for the delay:

56116 
248936 
53659 
34311 
233488 
54921 
47904 
45765 
31454 
55633 
55870 
55607 
32363 
219810 
211400 
216358 
274039 
244635 
152282 
151779 
43057 
37442 
251658 
53813 
56237 
259858 
252275 
251099

And here's some output typical of what I get when I spin to create the delay:

276461 
280869 
276215 
280850 
188066 
280666 
281139 
280904 
277886 
279250 
244671 
240599 
279697 
280844 
159246 
271938 
263632 
260892 
238902 
255570 
265652 
274005 
273604 
150640 
279153 
281146 
280845 
248277

Can anyone help me understand this behavior? (Note, I have tried this program, compiled with Visual C++ 2010 Express, on five computers. It only shows this behavior on the two fastest machines I have.)

Comment: Sleep only guarantees a minimum time.  After the time expires it will wait for the next available time slice before resuming.

Comment: Sleep() does what it says, it literally puts the processor to sleep.  It does absolutely nothing, stopped by the HLT instruction.  It can only be woken up by an interrupt.  Those interrupts are periodic, by default they fire 64 times per second.  So actual sleep time is 15.625 or 31.250 or 46.875 etc msec.  That can be messed with, start Chrome for example.  Underlying call it uses is timeBeginPeriod().  More well-behaved browsers change the rate to 10 msec.  So you get 10 or 20 or 30 or 40, etc.  Getting 33 msec requires changing the period to 1 msec.

Comment: That's true, but it wouldn't explain why code that executes after Sleep() returns runs slowly for a while.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) again. You are basing your reasoning off of rules that do not coincide with reality. Also relevant: [Windows Timer Coalescing](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=246618). @RichardCritten: That's not what the documentation says. A `Sleep` does not guarantee the minimum you are talking about.

Comment: @IInspectable 20 , I understand that, but  why would anything that runs after Sleep() returns run any differently than if it were preceded by a spin instead of Sleep()? I'm not timing the delay before runInPlace() is called. I'm timing how fast runInPlace runs after the delay. How could Sleep() affect anything that runs after Sleep() returns, regardless of how long Sleep slept?

Comment: @IInspectable "After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. If you specify 0 milliseconds, the thread will relinquish the remainder of its time slice but remain ready. Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses.". Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten: You also need to read the Remarks section: *"If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time. [...]"*

Comment: I suspect there is a cache-locality improvement in the case where you have already called `QueryPerformanceCounter()` a number of times.

Comment: Thanks, @EJP, you actually addressed my question. Caching issues crossed my mind too, but I wouldn't expect that slow-down effect to appear <i>after</i> runInPlace() had ever run at full speed in that case, and, when I run it more than once after the inter-call delay, it sometimes does. This is really one of the strangest behaviors I've seen in code in quite a while.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like it is due to the reduced clock speed that the CPU will run at when the computer is not busy (SpeedStep).  When the computer is idle (like in a sleep) the clock speed will drop to reduce power consumption.  On newer CPUs this can be 35% or less of the listed clock speed.  Once the computer gets busy again there is a small delay before the CPU will speed up again.

You can turn off this feature (either in the BIOS or by changing the "Minimum processor state" setting under "Processor power management" in the advanced settings of your power plan to 100%.

Comment: You nailed it @1201ProgramAlarm ! My minimum processor speed was set to 5%. I set it to 100% and the behavior has consistently vanished. Restoring the setting to 5% instantly returned the behavior. I honestly never would have thought of that, as I would have expected the speed to change much more quickly on its own, and I would also assume so much else was going on in my computer that a meaningful drop wasn't going to happen. Amazing. Thanks for the answer and for actually reading my question.

Comment: @StevensMiller: Modern CPUs are fast enough to not be useless at their most efficient speed.  OSes don't jump to max speed until they've seen a process use its entire timeslice a few times, indicating that is has more work to do than it can keep up with at this clock speed.  Otherwise it is actually best to leave the CPU at a low clock speed, because it's "fast enough" for whatever the CPU is doing.  Intel Skylake moves the decision making into the CPU, so it can respond much more quickly to load and to non-load (microseconds instead of milliseconds).

Comment: You only need to make your computer less efficient if this behaviour is actually causing a problem (e.g. realtime guarantees not being met in responding to the first request after a gap).  Even so, you could make the minimum speed 80% or something.  Speed increases also require increased voltage, so power increases more than linearly with frequency.  The total energy to do a given computation increases if you do it faster.  (race-to-sleep works well, but running at a more efficient speed is better until you get down to the minimum voltage for correct operation at any clock speed).

Answer (score 6):

Besides what *@1201ProgramAlarm* said (which may very well be, modern processors are extremely fond of downclocking whenever they can), it may also be a cache warming up problem.

When you ask to sleep for a while the scheduler typically schedules another thread/process for the next CPU time quantum, which means that the caches (instruction cache, data  cache, TLB, branch predictor data, ...) relative to your process are going to be "cold" again when your code regains the CPU.

Comment: Thanks, @Matteo Italia. Looks like 1201ProgramAlarm got it right, but your thoughts are also relevant and I'll have them in mind for anything similar. I'm grateful to you both for reading my question carefully enough to know what I was really asking. As some of the early comments show, almost any question involving Sleep provokes a discussion about granularity and accuracy, concepts that aren't relevant here. Cheers, fellows!